# How to see the same as RStudio "Global Environment" in VSCode?

Tags: julia, rstudio, visual-studio-code

I am learning how to code in Julia language and for that, I am using VSCode. However, I cannot find how to visualize the equivalent to the "Global Environment" that we have in the upper-right corner in R Studio.

"Global Environment" in the upper-right corner in R Studio:

[image]

Is there a way to set this up so I can constantly see the objects (variables) that I create in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our equivalent to that is the Julia Workspace, which you can focus by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-P</kbd> (might be <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on MacOS) to bring up the command palette and then typing in `Julia: Focus on Workspace View`. Then open a REPL and type in e.g. `a = collect(1:10)`; you should see something like
[image]

then.

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much! That is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You already received the response for VSCode.
However, if you are particularly attached to this functionality, until VSCode get a bit more polished, I find the workspace of Juno still better:

[image]

Comment: Yeah! I've hear of juno and I saw that too! Thank you very much!